# INSERT INTO MicrosoftAccess

Tags: sql

```
INSERT INTO Exam ( YourNumber, Name, Facultet, Number, NameCompetitions, Money, Score)

SELECT 15,'A B C', 'IBM', '13-vl', 'ART', 1000, 4
FROM Exam
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT YourNumber 
                 FROM Student 
                 WHERE Student.YourNumber =15) 
AND EXISTS(SELECT NameCompetitions 
           FROM Competitions 
           WHERE Competitions.NameCompetitions ='ART');
```

What's wrong?

Comment: This line will insert the same row over and over again.. **SELECT 15,'A B C', 'IBM', '13-vl', 'ART', 1000, 4** for every match. Is that your intent?

Comment: and neither exists has any correlation to Exam so you will insert that SELECT row as many  times as there are records in the EXAM table

Comment: I need to insert this line once

Comment: just remove `FROM Exam`. I can't test if MsAccess accepts a SELECT without a table name but most other products do. Otherwise change the SELECT to SELECT DISTINCT.